# undefined tags when read exif data in php

Tags: php, metadata, exif

I am trying to read EXIF data of images using php function `exif_read_data` but i it return some UndefinedTag what are these tags and why it is undefined

this is the code that i used

```
$exif = exif_read_data('3.jpeg', 0, true );

foreach($exif['IFD0'] as $key => $section)
{

    echo "$key . $section <br >";

}
```

it return

```
UndefinedTag:0x0025 . 14 Dec 2016  
UndefinedTag:0x0028 . Instruction 
UndefinedTag:0x002D . Referance Service
UndefinedTag:0x0050 . Rory McCrossan 
UndefinedTag:0x0055 . John 
UndefinedTag:0x005A . Tokyo
UndefinedTag:0x005F . Tokyo 
UndefinedTag:0x0064 . 3166 
UndefinedTag:0x0065 . japan 
UndefinedTag:0x006E . Climix  
UndefinedTag:0x0074 . Copyright 2016 
ImageDescription . SuzoPark
Software . Picasa 
Exif_IFD_Pointer . 744 
GPS_IFD_Pointer . 840
```

Comment: Did you try dumping the contents of the $exif variable before entering the foreach loop?

Answer (score -1):

Try dumping the contents of the $exif variable just before entering the foreach loop to see if the key 'IFD0' exists before trying to access it in the foreach loop like you did in your code. However, this code should print all the tags for you:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('3.jpeg', 0, true );
//print_r($exif);
//OR var_dump($exif); 
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
   foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
    echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
   }
}
```

The PHP manual on the exif_read_data() function gives more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php. Goodluck!

Note: Uncomment print_r($exif) or var_dump($exif) to examine $exif variable.